# Retrieve Selection from Dropdown and Populate List

Tags: jquery, element, populate

I need to retrieve all of the selected values of each dropdown list on a page, and populate a unordered list with these values. A new li element per item of course.

Currently I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        var sel = "";
        $(this).find(":selected").each(function() {
            sel += $(this).text() + " ";
        });
        $(".size-result").text(sel);
    });
});​
```

How do I go about using this to create a new li element and then insert the text?

I got it working with this, thanks to wirey:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        var sel = "";
    $(".option-select option:selected").each(function () {
       sel += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $(".result").empty().append(sel);
    }); 
});
```

Is there a way I can negate the first entry of every dropdown? Since it is a "Select..." or "Choose one..." value I would like to prevent it from showing since it is the first value in the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newLI = '';
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {           
           newLI += '<li>' + $(this).text() + "</li>";              
    });
    $('ulselector').append(newLI);
});​
```

Edit:

You can listen for a change in each dropdown and reupdate the list on each change

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('select').change(function(){ // <-- bind change event handler to the drop downs
        var newLI = '';
        $("select option:selected").each(function() {   // <-- then iterate each time it changes   
              newLI += '<li>' + $(this).text() + "</li>";              
        });
        $('ulselector').empty().append(newLI); //<-- empty() to remove old list and update with new list
    });
});​
```

EDIT AGAIN:

You can check to see if the selected value's index is 0.. if it is then don't show

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() { // <-- bind change event handler to the drop downs
        var newLI = '';

        $("select option:selected").each(function() { // <-- then iterate each time it changes   
            if ($(this).index() !== 0) { // <-- only if not default
                newLI += '<li>' + $(this).text() + "</li>";
            }    
            $('ul').empty().append(newLI); //<-- empty() to remove old list and update with new list
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/bKWpg/

Comment: Thanks! Now I have to figure out how to update the li list when a selection in the dropdown changes. Any pointers?

Comment: After changing the couple " inconsistencies, the code doesn't seem to work. Granted i didn't mess with it much. Thank you very much for your help btw.

Comment: I have edited my question above, thanks for the help! Is there a way to negate the first option of all the selects since they are just place holders like "Select one.." etc. A way to prevent these from showing in the populated list.

Comment: @AjTroxell  I think that's what you want.. unless you want blank `li` there as a space holder - I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select option[selected]").each(function(i,e) {
            $("ul#list").append("<li>"+$(e).val()+"</li>");})​;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedArr = [];
var $ul = $('<ul />');
selectedArr = $("select option[selected=selected]").map(function() {
    return this.value
}).get();
$.each(selectedArr, function() {
   $ul.append('<li>' + this.slice(3));
});
$('body').append($ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select option[selected]").each( function() {
        $('<li>', {
             text: $(this).val()
        }).appendTo('ul#list');
});
```